# How to refresh div content without loosing the angularJS scope?

Tags: c#, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-core-mvc

Hi I've a comment section, where I've defined some angular scope like ng-show and ng-hide, now everytime when I post a new comment, I need to show in that comment section div, so I'm refreshing the div using the following code - 

`$("#comment-section").load(window.location.href + " #comment-section");`
but by doing this all the defined angularjs scope is not working.
Here's my screenshot -

[image: before posting comment or refreshing division]

after posting comment, 
[image: after posting comment and refreshing comment division]

My code -

```
//other code
<div id="comment-section">
 <div ng-show="(commentMenu=='show_@item.Id')" class="more float-right align-items-end dropdown">
                            <button type="button" id="more-comment-btn_@item.Id" class="more-vertical-btn dropdown-custom-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <span class="more-vertical-dot"></span>
                                <span class="more-vertical-dot"></span>
                                <span class="more-vertical-dot"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu-left dropdown-menu" style="transform: translate3d(-48px, 31px, 0px);">


                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="ShowEdit='editComment_@item.Id'"><i class="fa fa-pen"></i> Edit</a></li>

                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="DeleteComment('@item.Id');"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
</div>
// other code
```

Please guys, I'm stuck here, a help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should just retrieve the comments with an XHR request and not refresh.

Comment: From controller. I'm passing data to a PartialView for Comments and rendering those data in this View.